# A remark to an IMO problem.

Tags: number-theory

In Andreescu's *Number Theory: Structures, Examples, and Problems*, the author offers a problem (2.1.19), and its respective, from the 33rd IMO:

**Problem 2.1.19.**

*For each positive integer n, denote by s(n) the greatest integer
such that for all positive integers k ≤ s(n), $n^2 $ can be expressed as a sum of squares of k positive integers.*

*(a) Prove that $s(n) ≤ n^2 − 14 $ for all n ≥ 4.*

*(b) Find a number n such that $s(n) = n^2 − 14 $.*

*(c) Prove that there exist infinitely many positive integers n such that
$s(n) = n^2 − 14 $.*

**Solution.**

*(a) Representing $n^2 $as a sum of $n^2 − 13 $ squares is equivalent to representing 13 as a sum of numbers of the form $x^2 −1 $, x ∈ N, such as 0, 3, 8, 15,... But it is easy to check that this is impossible, and hence $s(n) ≤ n^2 − 14 $.*

*(b) Let us prove that $s(13) = 13^2 − 14 = 155 $. Observe that
$13^2 = 8^2 + 8^2 + 4^2 + 4^2 + 3^2 $
$= 8^2 + 8^2 + 4^2 + 4^2 + 2^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 $
$= 8^2 + 8^2 + 4^2 + 3^2 + 3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 $.
Given any representation of $n^2 $ as a sum of m squares one of which is even,
we can construct a representation as a sum of m + 3 squares by dividing the
square into four equal squares. Thus the first equality enables us to construct
representations with 5, 8, 11,..., 155 squares, the second to construct ones with
7, 10, 13,..., 154 squares, and the third with 9, 12,..., 153 squares. It remains
only to represent $13^2 $ as a sum of k = 2, 3, 4, 6 squares. This can be done as follows:
$13^2 = 12^2 + 5^2 = 12^2 + 4^2 + 3^2 $
$= 11^2 + 4^2 + 4^2 + 4^2 $
$= 12^2 + 3^2 + 2^2 + 2^2 + 2^2 + 2^2 $.*

(c) *We shall prove that whenever $s(n) = n^2 − 14 $ for some n ≥ 13, it also
holds that $s(2n) = (2n)^2 − 14 $. This will imply that $s(n) = n^2 − 14 $ for any $n = 2^t · 13 $.
If $n^2 = x_1^2 +···+ x_r^2 $, then we have $(2n)^2 = (2x_1)^2 +···+(2x_r)^2 $. Replacing $(2x_i)^2 $ with $x_i^2 + x_i^2 +x_i^2 +x_i^2 $ as long as it is possible, we can obtain representations of $(2n)^2 $ consisting of $r,r +3,..., 4r $ squares. This gives representations of $(2n)^2 $ into k squares for any k ≤ $4n^2−62 $. Further, we observe that each number m ≥ 14 can be written as a sum of k ≥ m numbers of the form $x^2 − 1 $, x ∈ N, which is easy to verify. Therefore if $2n^2 ≤ k ≤ 4n^2 − 14 $, it follows that $4n^2 − k $ is a sum of k numbers of the form $x^2 − 1 $ (since k ≥ $4n^2 − k $≥ 14), and consequently $4n^2 $ is a sum of k squares.*

I cannot solve the remark Andreescu shared for this problem.

**Remark.** One can find exactly the value of $s(n) $ for each n:

$s(n)= $

$=1 $, if n has a prime divisor congruent to 3 mod 4

$=2 $, if n is of form $5\cdot2^k $, where k is a positive integer

$=n^2-14 $, otherwise.

Comment: The remark says that $s(4)=2$ and $s(5)=11$, but I don't think these are correct.

Comment: @mathlove You are right. I am not sure if the function includes n=4, and the author might've meant to state k is nonnegative instead of positive.

Comment: The remark says that $s(2^t)=(2^t)^2-14$, but we have $s(2^t)=1$ since $(2^t)^2$ cannot be expressed as a sum of squares of two positive integers.